# Differentiate the Function $g(x)= \ln\ \frac{a-x}{a+x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$g(x)= \ln\ \frac{a-x}{a+x}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}\ =\frac{d}{dx}\ \ln \frac{a-x}{a+x}$$

$$g'(x) = \frac{1}{\frac{a-x}{a+x}}\cdot\frac{1}{1}\ \ln\ \frac{a+x}{a-x}$$

$$g'(x)=  \frac{a+x}{a-x}$$

This answer is wrong. What steps am I failing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \dfrac{a-x}{a+x}$ then $f'(x) = - \dfrac{2a}{(a+x)^2}$ by the quotient rule. So utilising the chain rule, we have $$g'(x) = - \dfrac{2a}{(a+x)^2} \cdot \frac{a+x}{a-x} = -\frac{2a}{(a+x)(a-x)}$$

---

A more elegant approach just occurred to me: $g(x) = \ln (a-x) - \ln (a+x)$. So $$g'(x) = \frac{-1}{a-x} - \frac{1}{a+x} = -\frac{2a}{(a+x)(a-x)}$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25419/discussion-on-answer-by-chickenp-differentiate-the-function-gx-ln-fraca).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the rule

$$\left(\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}\right)'=\frac{u'(x)v(x)-v'(x)u(x)}{v(x)^2}$$

to calculate the inner derivate.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use $$\ln\left(\frac{a-x}{a+x}\right)=\ln(a-x)-\ln(a+x).$$

---

With the same trick, you easily process complex products and quotients:

$$\left(\ln\left(\frac {abc}{de}\right)\right)'=\frac{\left(\frac{abc}{de}\right)'}{\frac{abc}{de}}=(\ln(a)+\ln(b)+\ln(c)-\ln(d)-\ln(e))'=\frac{a'}a+\frac{b'}b+\frac{c'}c-\frac{d}d-\frac{e'}e,$$
and
$$\left(\frac{abc}{de}\right)'=\frac{abc}{de}\left(\frac{a'}a+\frac{b'}b+\frac{c'}c-\frac{d}d-\frac{e'}e\right).$$

Comment: $\ln\left(\frac{a-x}{a+x}\right)=\ln(a-x)-\ln(a+x).$

Comment: @user26486: you were faster than me.

Comment: it's still not correct.

Comment: @user26486: shame on me !